# Add data to store in cakephp3 controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using [cakephp-3.0](/questions/tagged/cakephp-3.0) but I have a problem in the version of cakephp 2.x I can add data in controller and I don't need to send it from the view.

example:

```
public function add()
{
    $this->request->data['User']['id']=$this->Auth->user('id');//and save id
    $this->request->data['User']['date']=$date('Y-m-d H:m:s');// and save date
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {            
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The user has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

up here, add data to it already received, receive an information and that data added the id and date for example. Is just a example. and if I save this information, the information is saved with id and date. id and date are not necessarily in the view.

now I want to do something similar in cakephp 3 but dont work.

```
   public function add()
   {
    $user = $this->Users->newEntity();
    $this->request->data['User']['id']=$this->Auth->user('id');//and don't save id
    $this->request->data['User']['date']=$date('Y-m-d H:m:s');// and don't save date
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {

        $this->request['date'] = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
        $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
        debug($user);
        if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
            $this->Flash->success('The user has been saved.');
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.');
        }
    }
    $this->set(compact('user'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['user']);
}
```

search the documentation and found something that I explain this more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

old:

```
$this->request->data['User']['id']=$this->Auth->user('id');//and don't save id
$this->request->data['User']['date']=$date('Y-m-d H:m:s');// and don't save date
```

new:

```
$user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data);
$user->id=$this->Auth->user('id');
$user->date=$date('Y-m-d H:m:s');
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this isn't working any more:

```
$this->request->data['User']['id']
```

It's now

```
$this->request->data['id']
```

Before messing around blind you should [read the migration guide](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices.html) and maybe do the blog tutorial for CakePHP 3.0 to learn about the differences, this will save you a lot of time.

Comment: try this but does not work when I want to assign data to the variable id.

Comment: Either your question or your code doesn't make any sense then. Refine your question.